# How can i shift the light gallery thumbnails at the bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightgallery

I am using `light gallery`.

> http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/

I want to the position of thumbnails to be at the top instead of bottom. Anyone encountered such an issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its easy with css (ofc you can do with js/jquery or even editing source file).

add this line of css in your stylesheet or the plugin style sheet in very last line:

`.lg-outer .lg-thumb-outer {top:0 !important;bottom: auto !important;}`

Comment: I tried this myself as well but the issue is that the top bar then overlaps with thumbnail area.

Comment: Same thing happens when the thumbnails are in bottom. When you pull up the thumbnails from bottom to the top they just overlap some buttons like zoom, auto play and so on. To fix that issue you can add `.lg-outer .lg-thumb-outer {top:50px !important;bottom: auto !important;}` instead top one.